# Figuring which printer name corresponds to which device ID

Tags: winapi, printing, createfile

My goal is to open a printer connected via USB using the `CreateFile` (and then issue some `WriteFile`s and `ReadFile`s).

If the printer was an LPT one, I would simply do `CreateFile("LPT1:", ...)`. But for USB printers, there is a special device path that must be passed to `CreateFile` in order to open that printer.

This device path, [as I was able to find](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/52713-communicating-with-usb-printer/), is retrieved via [`SetupDiGetClassDevs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069.aspx) -> [`SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551015.aspx) -> [`SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120.aspx) -> [`DevicePath` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552343.aspx) and looks like this:

> `\\?\usb#vid_0a5f&pid_0027#46a072900549#{28d78fad-5a12-11d1-ae5b-0000f803a8c2}`

All that is fine, but what I have as the input is the human-readable printer name, as seen in `Devices and Printers`. The `SetupDi*` functions don't seem to use that, they only operate on [device instance IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541327.aspx). So the question is now **how to get device instance ID from the printer name one would pass to `OpenPrinter`**.

It's not difficult to observe that the GUID part of the above is the `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBPRINT`, and `\\?\usb` is fixed, so the only bit I'm really interested in is `vid_0a5f&pid_0027#46a072900549#`. This path I can easily look up manually in the printer properties dialog:

> Go to Devices and Printers
>   Right-click the printer
>   Properties
>   Switch to Hardware tab
>   Select the printing device, such as ZDesigner LP2844-Z
>   Properties
>   Switch to Details tab
>   Select 'Parent' from the dropdown.

But I have no idea how to do that programmatically provided the only thing given is the printer name as seen in the Device and Printers panel.

---

P.S. 1: I'm not interested in opening the printer with `OpenPrinter` and then using `WritePrinter` / `ReadPrinter`. That has been done, works fine, but now the goal is different.

P.S. 2: **I'll be OK with a simpler way to convert the readable printer name to something that can be passed to `CreateFile`**.

P.S. 3: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846340/reading-status-from-zebra-printer), to which I have posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659778/11683), is very related to what I ultimately want to do.

P.S. 4: The other way round is also fine: **If it is possible to obtain the readable name from the [`SP_DEVINFO_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552344.aspx) structure, that will also be the answer**, although a less convenient one.

Comment: I'm probably being dumb, but can you not use the [`USBPRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546285(v=vs.85).aspx) identifiers?

Comment: @eggyal Didn't know about those, but they seem to be model identifiers rather than device identifiers (we have several identical printers installed on one machine). Besides, `CreateFile` fails when presented with `"USBPRINT\Zebra_TechnologiesZT9FD5"`.

Comment: Fair enough - I'm way out of my depth here... I think you probably want to use the [PnP Configuration Manager Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example [`CM_Get_Device_ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (at worst you can use [`CM_Get_Device_ID_List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and loop through until you find the printer you want), but we'll have to await someone who knows the API better to help more.

Comment: Only connected printers should be counted, I suppose?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Yes, obviously. The found path is immediately passed to `CreateFile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is what I finally have been able to come up with.

**Please confirm that `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\{0}\PNPData` is a supported path**, and not just happens to be there in the current implementation, subject to future changes.

There's a little problem with structure alignment, for which I've posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728644/properly-declare-sp-device-interface-detail-data-for-pinvoke).

```
public static class UsbPrinterResolver
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public Guid ClassGuid;
        public uint DevInst;
        public IntPtr Reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
        public uint Flags;
        public IntPtr Reserved;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 1)]
    private struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA  // Only used for Marshal.SizeOf. NOT!
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public char DevicePath;
    }


    [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern uint CM_Get_Parent(out uint pdnDevInst, uint dnDevInst, uint ulFlags);

    [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern uint CM_Get_Device_ID(uint dnDevInst, string Buffer, uint BufferLen, uint ulFlags);

    [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern uint CM_Get_Device_ID_Size(out uint pulLen, uint dnDevInst, uint ulFlags);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs([In(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] System.Guid ClassGuid, string Enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, uint Flags);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, uint MemberIndex, ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, [In()] ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, [In(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] System.Guid InterfaceClassGuid, uint MemberIndex, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, [In()] ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData, IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData, uint DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, out uint RequiredSize, IntPtr DeviceInfoData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, int dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    private const uint DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002U;
    private const uint DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000010U;
    private const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
    private const uint CR_SUCCESS = 0;

    private const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;
    private const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;
    private const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    private const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    private const int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;

    private static readonly Guid GUID_PRINTER_INSTALL_CLASS = new Guid(0x4d36e979, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18);
    private static readonly Guid GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBPRINT = new Guid(0x28d78fad, 0x5a12, 0x11D1, 0xae, 0x5b, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x03, 0xa8, 0xc2);
    private static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);


    private static string GetPrinterRegistryInstanceID(string PrinterName) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PrinterName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("PrinterName");

        const string key_template = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\{0}\PNPData";

        using (var hk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                            string.Format(key_template, PrinterName),
                            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default,
                            System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.QueryValues
                        )
               )
        {

            if (hk == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PrinterName", "This printer does not have PnP data.");

            return (string)hk.GetValue("DeviceInstanceId");
        }
    }

    private static string GetPrinterParentDeviceId(string RegistryInstanceID) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RegistryInstanceID)) throw new ArgumentNullException("RegistryInstanceID");

        IntPtr hdi = SetupDiGetClassDevs(GUID_PRINTER_INSTALL_CLASS, RegistryInstanceID, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF_PRESENT);
        if (hdi.Equals(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

        try
        {
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA printer_data = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
            printer_data.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));

            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hdi, 0, ref printer_data) == 0) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();   // Only one device in the set

            uint cmret = 0;

            uint parent_devinst = 0;
            cmret = CM_Get_Parent(out parent_devinst, printer_data.DevInst, 0);
            if (cmret != CR_SUCCESS) throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to get parent of the device '{0}'. Error code: 0x{1:X8}", RegistryInstanceID, cmret));


            uint parent_device_id_size = 0;
            cmret = CM_Get_Device_ID_Size(out parent_device_id_size, parent_devinst, 0);
            if (cmret != CR_SUCCESS) throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to get size of the device ID of the parent of the device '{0}'. Error code: 0x{1:X8}", RegistryInstanceID, cmret));

            parent_device_id_size++;  // To include the null character

            string parent_device_id = new string('\0', (int)parent_device_id_size);
            cmret = CM_Get_Device_ID(parent_devinst, parent_device_id, parent_device_id_size, 0);
            if (cmret != CR_SUCCESS) throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to get device ID of the parent of the device '{0}'. Error code: 0x{1:X8}", RegistryInstanceID, cmret));

            return parent_device_id;
        }
        finally
        {
            SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hdi);
        }
    }

    private static string GetUSBInterfacePath(string SystemDeviceInstanceID) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SystemDeviceInstanceID)) throw new ArgumentNullException("SystemDeviceInstanceID");

        IntPtr hdi = SetupDiGetClassDevs(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBPRINT, SystemDeviceInstanceID, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        if (hdi.Equals(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

        try
        {
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA device_data = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
            device_data.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));

            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hdi, 0, ref device_data) == 0) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();  // Only one device in the set

            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA interface_data = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
            interface_data.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA));

            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hdi, ref device_data, GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USBPRINT, 0, ref interface_data) == 0) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();   // Only one interface in the set


            // Get required buffer size
            uint required_size = 0;
            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdi, ref interface_data, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out required_size, IntPtr.Zero);

            int last_error_code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (last_error_code != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(last_error_code);

            IntPtr interface_detail_data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)required_size);

            try
            {

                // FIXME, don't know how to calculate the size.
                // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728644/properly-declare-sp-device-interface-detail-data-for-pinvoke

                switch (IntPtr.Size)
                {
                    case 4:
                        Marshal.WriteInt32(interface_detail_data, 4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Marshal.WriteInt32(interface_detail_data, 8);
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException("Architecture not supported.");
                }

                if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdi, ref interface_data, interface_detail_data, required_size, out required_size, IntPtr.Zero) == 0) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

                // TODO: When upgrading to .NET 4, replace that with IntPtr.Add
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(new IntPtr(interface_detail_data.ToInt64() + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA), "DevicePath").ToInt64()));

            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(interface_detail_data);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hdi);
        }
    }


    public static string GetUSBPath(string PrinterName) {
        return GetUSBInterfacePath(GetPrinterParentDeviceId(GetPrinterRegistryInstanceID(PrinterName)));
    }

    public static Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle OpenUSBPrinter(string PrinterName) {
        return new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle(CreateFile(GetUSBPath(PrinterName), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero), true);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
using (var sh = UsbPrinterResolver.OpenUSBPrinter("Zebra Large"))
{
    using (var f = new System.IO.FileStream(sh, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        // Read from and write to the stream f
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your sample and it gets to the point of: `SetupDIEnumDeviceInfo(hdi, 0, ref printer_data)` and this returns false. I called `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` and my error code is 259. I'm stumped. My printer is plugged into USB, and shows in registry.

Comment: The above code should work for Plug and Play installed printers (majority of consumer printers). In my case, the printer wasn't installed via PnP and accordingly the PNPData key did not exist. It should also be noted that hard-linked registry key lookups like this aren't recommended as registry organization is subject to change. However, I haven't yet found an API function(s) to establish a relationship between a Printer Name in Devices and Printers and its actual device.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (Python code):

```
import _winreg

HKLM = _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def getDevicePath(printerName):
    key = _winreg.OpenKey(HKLM,
        r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\%s" \
        % printerName)

    value =_winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "Port")[0]
    assert value.startswith("USB"), \
           "Port does not start with 'USB': %s" % value

    printerPortNumber = int(value.replace(u"USB", u""))

    key = _winreg.OpenKey(HKLM,
            r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses" \
            r"\{28d78fad-5a12-11d1-ae5b-0000f803a8c2}")

    idx = 0
    devicePath = None
    while True:
        try:
            subKeyName = _winreg.EnumKey(key, idx)
            subKey = _winreg.OpenKey(key, subKeyName)

            try:
                subSubKey = _winreg.OpenKey(subKey, r"#\Device Parameters")
                baseName = _winreg.QueryValueEx(subSubKey, "Base Name")[0]
                portNumber = _winreg.QueryValueEx(subSubKey, "Port Number")[0]
                if baseName == "USB" and portNumber == printerPortNumber:
                    devicePath = subKeyName.replace("##?#USB", r"\\?\usb")
                    break

            except WindowsError:
                continue

            finally:
                idx += 1

        except WindowsError:
            break

    return devicePath
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ... let me know if this helps ...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_PnPEntity");
        foreach (ManagementObject device in s.Get())
        {
            // Try Name, Caption and/or Description (they seem to be same most of the time).
            string Name = (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Name");

            // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Query String ...
            if (Name == "O2Micro Integrated MMC/SD controller")
            {
                /*
                 class Win32_PnPEntity : CIM_LogicalDevice
                {
                  uint16   Availability;
                  string   Caption;
                  string   ClassGuid;
                  string   CompatibleID[];
                  uint32   ConfigManagerErrorCode;
                  boolean  ConfigManagerUserConfig;
                  string   CreationClassName;
                  string   Description;
                  string   DeviceID;
                  boolean  ErrorCleared;
                  string   ErrorDescription;
                  string   HardwareID[];
                  datetime InstallDate;
                  uint32   LastErrorCode;
                  string   Manufacturer;
                  string   Name;
                  string   PNPDeviceID;
                  uint16   PowerManagementCapabilities[];
                  boolean  PowerManagementSupported;
                  string   Service;
                  string   Status;
                  uint16   StatusInfo;
                  string   SystemCreationClassName;
                  string   SystemName;
                };
                */

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name         : {0}", Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("DeviceID     : {0}", device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"));
                    Console.WriteLine("PNPDeviceID  : {0}", device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"));
                    Console.WriteLine("ClassGuid    : {0}", device.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid"));
                    Console.WriteLine("HardwareID   :\n{0}", JoinStrings(device.GetPropertyValue("HardwareID") as string[]));
                    Console.WriteLine("CompatibleID :\n{0}", JoinStrings(device.GetPropertyValue("CompatibleID") as string[]));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static string JoinStrings(string[] sarray)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        if (sarray != null)
        {
            foreach (string s in sarray)
                b.Append("        '" + s + "'\n");
        }
        return b.ToString();
    }
```

Don't have a USB printer to test against, but this provides the information you are looking for (including for USB devices)...

```
Description  : O2Micro Integrated MMC/SD controller
DeviceID     : PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221&SUBSYS_04931028&REV_05\4&26B31A7F&0&00E5
PNPDeviceID  : PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221&SUBSYS_04931028&REV_05\4&26B31A7F&0&00E5
ClassGuid    : {4d36e97b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
HardwareID   :
        'PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221&SUBSYS_04931028&REV_05'
        'PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221&SUBSYS_04931028'
        'PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221&CC_080501'
        'PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221&CC_0805'

CompatibleID :         'PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221&REV_05'
        'PCI\VEN_1217&DEV_8221'
        'PCI\VEN_1217&CC_080501'
        'PCI\VEN_1217&CC_0805'
        'PCI\VEN_1217'
        'PCI\CC_080501'
        'PCI\CC_0805'
```

Also, for a URI, change the '\'s to '#'s in the URI you are intending of building.

so ..

```
usb\vid_0a5f&pid_0027\46a072900549\{28d78fad-5a12-11d1-ae5b-0000f803a8c2}
```

becomes

```
usb#vid_0a5f&pid_0027#46a072900549#{28d78fad-5a12-11d1-ae5b-0000f803a8c2}
```

====

As GSerg pointed out that Win32_Printer Class helps with the above code, but doesn't provide the device id.

But if I use Win32_Printer class and print out the "PortName" property, that, for the printers I have installed gives be a port/filename that I can use with CreateFile() and open the device.

e.g.:

```
Name         : Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Description  :
DeviceID     : Microsoft XPS Document Writer
PNPDeviceID  :
PortName  : XPSPort:


Name         : Fax
Description  :
DeviceID     : Fax
PNPDeviceID  :
PortName  : SHRFAX:
```

Here, writing to "XPSPORT:" or "SHRFAX:" sends data to the printer. What does this do for your USB printer?

Comment: This is promising; however, it does not help as of now. The `Name` it gives is not the name of the printer, it is the name of the driver. So again, I have no way of knowing whether that is the correct printer or not. And if I instead query `Win32_Printer`, then `PNPDeviceID` is blank, and `DeviceID` is useless (same as the printer name).

Comment: does the PortName property help?

Comment: No, `PortName` does not help. It is `USB002`, and `CreateFile` fails to open that. On contrary, if the port was "LPT1:", it would succeed. If you know how to make `CreateFile` open something like `USB002`, that would definitely be the answer.

Comment: Have you tried .. \\.\USB002 ?? Also remembered that if the printer is shared then you can directly open the printer by name: "\\machine-name\printer-name".

Comment: Yes, I've tried `\\.\USB002` and `\\?\USB002`. The printer is not shared and will not be.

Comment: Problem is that Printer is printer itself (with same name as driver) and PrintQueue (with name visible in Windows) is another device :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `WinObj` from Microsoft to get the specific device name. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx .  This will quickly get you the proper device name to use with `CreateFile` to write directly to your USB printer or simply writing directly to a USB printer adapter with old school parallel port output for custom circuitry!

To open the port associated with a specific printer, you may need to use `ntcreatefile`.  Use the `EnumPrinters` function to return a `printer_info_2` structure containing the port name for each printer.  This port name can then be opened with `ntcreatefile` (an NT internal version of `CreateFile`) which is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380(v=vs.85).aspx

Why does this work?  There are three namespace levels in windows NT file/device names and the port name retrieved from `EnumPrinters` can only be opened with `ntcreatefile` because it is only in the NT namespace.  There may be an equivalent win32 namespace link for certain devices and roundabout ways to match them with a printer name but this is difficult as others have shown in prior answers.

Check out the `Global??` folder in `WinObj` tool to show the symbolic links between win32 namespace and NT namespace on your machine.  The old school `COM1`, `COM2`, `LPT1`, etc. device names are simply windows NT namespace symbolic links as well.  Google "win32 nt namespace" for a more detailed explanation. (Sorry, but as a new user, I can only post 2 hyperlinks.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a c++ guy, but I don't really think trying to generate the device id from the name is the way to go. However, you can

1. Use [`EnumPrinters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and read the [`PRINTER_INFO_2 structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the driver name, and then read the driver details from registry like in [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6866/Enumerate-Properties-of-an-Installed-Device).
2. Generate the name for yourself by finding out the printer details possibly from the [PRINTER INFO structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and constructing it correctly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553356(v=vs.85).aspx for details.

**EDIT:** You can actually get names + device instance ids of printers from registry:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\

Comment: It's not about C++, I'm happy with any language (and in fact, I'm using C# for this project), I just picked C++ as the easiest way to start playing with the API and structures without having a need to declare PInvoke attributes etc. The driver name is useless because it is same for the identical printers I have installed. If you look at [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10728780/11683) to this question, I'm already doing something similar to what you linked to, but I'm not sure if reading the registry in this way is supported (as opposed to implementation-dependent).

Comment: Hmm, if you are doing C#, then what is the need for the API calls?

Comment: How else are you going to get that information? First translate redistry device ID to parent device ID, then the parent device ID to the usbprint interface path? .NET framework does not seem to provide a way.

Comment: I'm actually saying you don't even need to use the CreateFile and OpenPrinter api calls to get printer information when there is [WMI](http://aleemkhan.wordpress.com/2005/09/20/getting-printer-information-through-wmi/).

Comment: I don't need printer information for its own sake. I only need printer information in order to open that printer with `CreateFile`. It is not possible to get away with .NET printing subsystem, because it opens printer in a different way, via a spooler. WMI does not provide the required information, as I [have noted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651949/figuring-which-printer-name-corresponds-to-which-device-id/10770139#comment13918239_10711248) in a comment to PrashantGupta's answer.