# USB Serial Device with Virtual COM port - ReadFile() reads zero bytes if use CreateFile() with USB path

Tags: c++, winapi, usb

I have a point of sale application that uses Serial Communication ports (RS-232) to communicate with a scale for weighing products. I am now working on being able to support USB devices directly rather than using a Virtual Serial Communication port as they have an annoying tendency to move around.

What we have found is that while Windows 7 seems to automatically create the Virtual Serial Communication port, other versions of Windows such as POS Ready 7 may not. We suspect this is due to a specific .inf file with Windows 7 that is missing from POS Ready 7. Can someone confirm that?

I have a USB sample application that works intermittently. I am having a problem with the USB level communication with the `ReadFile()` Windows API function. I am using `CreateFile()` specifying the USB device path to obtain an I/O handle followed by using `WriteFile()` and `ReadFile()` to communicate with the scale. The `ReadFile()` is not providing data in some cases.

**Background Information**

The particular scale I am using, Brecknell 67xx bench scale, worked with using Virtual Serial Communication port directly out of the box with the point of sale application. I connected the scale to my Windows 7 PC with a USB cable and Windows automatically installed the drivers to create a Virtual Serial port, COM4 in my case. I then configured the application to talk to the scale through COM4 and everything worked fine.

The protocol for using the scale is to send a two byte command, "W\r" (capital letter W followed by a carriage return character) to the scale and to then read a 16 byte response which contains the current weight as well as status information about scale mechanics such as In Motion.

The sample USB application that I am learning from will work successfully providing a weight. Then it will stop working properly with the behavior of the `ReadFile()` returning zero bytes read. Once it stops working it will continue failing to provide data from the `ReadFile()` even if I unplug and replug the USB cable or restart my PC.

A previous version of the learning application was hanging on the `ReadFile()` and when a Break All was done with Visual Studio, a pause followed by a message indicating a deadlock would be displayed. However since I started using `SetCommTimeouts()` with a 5000 millisecond timeout value in `ReadTotalTimeoutConstant` I see a consistent 5 second pause before the `ReadFile()` returns with zero bytes read.

The strange thing is that if I then use the application which opens the Virtual Serial Communication port, COM4, that application works fine and the scale reports the weight of items.

I can then return to the sample application that uses direct USB rather than the Virtual Serial Communication port and it will work fine reporting weights.

However if I then unplug the USB cable connecting scale with PC, which powers off the scale as well, then plug the USB cable back in, the sample application no longer functions correctly and once again I see the pause with timeout.

Then I try using the original point of sale application that depends on Serial Communication ports using the Virtual Serial port, COM4, and that application weighs items just fine.

And when I then retry my sample application, it also will report item weights.

**My Questions.**

If a USB device creates a Virtual Serial Communications port when it is plugged in then is it required to only use the Virtual Serial port by specifying the communications port, COM4 in my case, in the `CreateFile()` call?

How is it possible to have direct USB serial communication by using `CreateFile()` with the USB device path if the device causes Windows to generate a Virtual Communication port?

Is there some way of specifying that any version of Windows is to automatically create a Virtual Serial Communications port for the device when it is plugged in?

**Source Code of the Sample USB Application**

The source code from my sample USB Windows Console application using Visual Studio 2005 is as follows with the main being at the bottom and much of this being the class for finding a particular USB device and then allowing `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()`:

```
// usb_test_cons.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <initguid.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// This is the GUID for the USB device class.
// It is defined in the include file Usbiodef.h of the Microsoft Windows Driver Kit.
// See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972(v=vs.85).aspx which
// provides basic documentation on this GUID.
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, 0xA5DCBF10L, 0x6530, 0x11D2, 0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED);
// (A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED)

// Following are standard defines to be used with all of the
// devices that are use through the UIE interface.
#define UIE_DEVICE_ERROR             (-11)        /* error when accessing the device */
#define UIE_DEVICE_NOT_PROVIDE       (-12)        /* device is not provided */
#define UIE_DEVICE_ERROR_RANGE       (-13)        /* range error         */
#define UIE_DEVICE_ERROR_COM         (-14)        /* communication error */
#define UIE_DEVICE_TIMEOUT           (-15)        /* communication error */
#define UIE_DEVICE_SPECIFIC          (-20)        /* device specific errors start here */


#define UIE_SCALE_ETX           0x03        /* ETX character         */
#define UIE_SCALE_IN_MOTION     0x01        /* scale in motion       */
#define UIE_SCALE_ZERO          0x02        /* zero weight           */
#define UIE_SCALE_UNDER         0x01        /* under capacity        */
#define UIE_SCALE_OVER          0x02        /* over capacity         */

#define UIE_SCALE_ERROR             UIE_DEVICE_ERROR          /* error          */
#define UIE_SCALE_NOT_PROVIDE       UIE_DEVICE_NOT_PROVIDE    /* not provide    */
#define UIE_SCALE_TIMEOUT           UIE_DEVICE_TIMEOUT        /* time out when reading from scale  */
#define UIE_SCALE_MOTION            (UIE_DEVICE_SPECIFIC-1)   /* motion         */
#define UIE_SCALE_UNDER_CAPACITY    (UIE_DEVICE_SPECIFIC-2)   /* under capacity */
#define UIE_SCALE_OVER_CAPACITY     (UIE_DEVICE_SPECIFIC-3)   /* over capacity  */
#define UIE_SCALE_DATAFORMAT        (UIE_DEVICE_SPECIFIC-4)   /* Data read from scale incorrect format in UieScaleAnalysis()  */
#define UIE_SCALE_DATAUNITS         (UIE_DEVICE_SPECIFIC-5)   /* Units read from scale incorrect in UieScaleAnalysis()  */


static SHORT UieScaleStatus(char *puchBuffer, DWORD sLength)
{
    UCHAR   uchByte;

    switch (sLength) {
        case 16:
            // The scale message is a weight message with a status section.
            // Move the buffer pointer to where the status section should begin.
            // A status only message has the same format as the status section of a weight message.
            puchBuffer += 10;
        case 6:
            // The scale message may be a status only message if there is a problem with the scale.
            // A status only message is 6 characters with the letter S as the second character.
            if (*(puchBuffer + 0) != '\n' ||
                *(puchBuffer + 1) != 'S'  ||
                *(puchBuffer + 4) != '\r' ||
                *(puchBuffer + 5) != UIE_SCALE_ETX) {
                return (UIE_SCALE_DATAFORMAT);               /* exit ... */
            }
            break;
        default:
            return (UIE_SCALE_DATAFORMAT);               /* exit ... */
            break;
    }

    /* --- check status of low byte --- */
    uchByte = *(puchBuffer + 3) - (UCHAR)0x30;

    if (uchByte & UIE_SCALE_UNDER) {
        return (UIE_SCALE_UNDER_CAPACITY);
    } else if (uchByte & UIE_SCALE_OVER) {
        return (UIE_SCALE_OVER_CAPACITY);
    }

    /* --- check status of high byte --- */
    uchByte = *(puchBuffer + 2) - (UCHAR)0x30;

    if (uchByte & UIE_SCALE_IN_MOTION) {
        return (UIE_SCALE_MOTION);
    } else if (uchByte & UIE_SCALE_ZERO) {
        return (0);
    } else {
        return (TRUE);
    }
}

class UsbSerialDevice
{
public:
    UsbSerialDevice();
    ~UsbSerialDevice();
    int CreateEndPoint (wchar_t *wszVendorId);
    int CloseEndPoint ();
    int ReadStream (void *bString, size_t nBytes);
    int WriteStream (void *bString, size_t nBytes);

    DWORD   m_dwError;          // GetLastError() for last action
    DWORD   m_dwErrorWrite;     // GetLastError() for last write
    DWORD   m_dwErrorRead;      // GetLastError() for last read
    DWORD   m_dwBytesWritten;
    DWORD   m_dwBytesRead;

private:
    HANDLE        m_hFile;
    DWORD         m_dwStatError;
    COMMTIMEOUTS  m_timeOut;
    COMSTAT       m_statOut;
};

UsbSerialDevice::UsbSerialDevice() :
    m_dwError(0),
    m_dwErrorWrite(0),
    m_dwErrorRead(0),
    m_dwBytesWritten(0),
    m_dwBytesRead(0),
    m_hFile(NULL)
{
}

UsbSerialDevice::~UsbSerialDevice()
{
    CloseHandle (m_hFile);
}

int UsbSerialDevice::WriteStream(void *bString, size_t nBytes)
{
    BOOL  bWrite = FALSE;

    if (m_hFile) {
        m_dwError = m_dwErrorWrite = 0;
        m_dwBytesWritten = 0;
        ClearCommError (m_hFile, &m_dwStatError, &m_statOut);
        bWrite = WriteFile (m_hFile, bString, nBytes, &m_dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        m_dwError = m_dwErrorWrite = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}

int UsbSerialDevice::ReadStream(void *bString, size_t nBytes)
{
    BOOL  bRead = FALSE;

    if (m_hFile) {
        m_dwError = m_dwErrorRead = 0;
        m_dwBytesRead = 0;
        ClearCommError (m_hFile, &m_dwStatError, &m_statOut);
        bRead = ReadFile (m_hFile, bString, nBytes, &m_dwBytesRead, NULL);
        m_dwError = m_dwErrorRead = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}

int UsbSerialDevice::CreateEndPoint (wchar_t *wszVendorId)
{
    HDEVINFO    hDevInfo;


    m_dwError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;

    // We will try to get device information set for all USB devices that have a
    // device interface and are currently present on the system (plugged in).
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, NULL, 0, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD    dwMemberIdx;
        BOOL     bContinue = TRUE;
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA         DevIntfData;

        // Prepare to enumerate all device interfaces for the device information
        // set that we retrieved with SetupDiGetClassDevs(..)
        DevIntfData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
        dwMemberIdx = 0;

        // Next, we will keep calling this SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(..) until this
        // function causes GetLastError() to return  ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS. With each
        // call the dwMemberIdx value needs to be incremented to retrieve the next
        // device interface information.
        for (BOOL bContinue = TRUE; bContinue; ) {
            PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA  DevIntfDetailData;
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA    DevData;
            DWORD  dwSize;

            dwMemberIdx++;
            SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, dwMemberIdx, &DevIntfData);

            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) break;

            // As a last step we will need to get some more details for each
            // of device interface information we are able to retrieve. This
            // device interface detail gives us the information we need to identify
            // the device (VID/PID), and decide if it's useful to us. It will also
            // provide a DEVINFO_DATA structure which we can use to know the serial
            // port name for a virtual com port.

            DevData.cbSize = sizeof(DevData);

            // Get the required buffer size. Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail with
            // a NULL DevIntfDetailData pointer, a DevIntfDetailDataSize
            // of zero, and a valid RequiredSize variable. In response to such a call,
            // this function returns the required buffer size at dwSize.

            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &DevIntfData, NULL, 0, &dwSize, NULL);

            // Allocate memory for the DeviceInterfaceDetail struct. Don't forget to
            // deallocate it later!
            DevIntfDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize);
            DevIntfDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

            if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &DevIntfData, DevIntfDetailData, dwSize, &dwSize, &DevData))
            {
                // Finally we can start checking if we've found a useable device,
                // by inspecting the DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath variable.
                //
                // The DevicePath looks something like this for a Brecknell 67xx Series Serial Scale
                // \\?\usb#vid_1a86&pid_7523#6&28eaabda&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
                //
                // The VID for a particular vendor will be the same for a particular vendor's equipment.
                // The PID is variable for each device of the vendor.
                //
                // As you can see it contains the VID/PID for the device, so we can check
                // for the right VID/PID with string handling routines.

                // See https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/usb/usbview/vndrlist.h

                if (wcsstr (DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath, wszVendorId)) {
                    m_dwError = 0;
                    m_hFile = CreateFile (DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
                    if (m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                        m_dwError = GetLastError();
                    } else {
                        GetCommTimeouts (m_hFile, &m_timeOut);
                        m_timeOut.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
                        m_timeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
                        m_timeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 5000;
                        SetCommTimeouts (m_hFile, &m_timeOut);
                        m_dwError = GetLastError();
                    }
                    bContinue = FALSE;    // found the vendor so stop processing after freeing the heap.
                }
            }

            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, DevIntfDetailData);
        }

        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    }

    return 0;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UsbSerialDevice  myDev;

    myDev.CreateEndPoint (L"vid_1a86&pid_7523");
    switch (myDev.m_dwError) {
        case 0:
            // no error so just ignore.
            break;
        case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
            wprintf (_T("   CreateFile() failed. GetLastError() = %d\n      ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED: Access is denied.\n      Is it already in use?\n"), myDev.m_dwError);
            break;
        case ERROR_GEN_FAILURE:
            wprintf (_T("   CreateFile() failed. GetLastError() = %d\n      ERROR_GEN_FAILURE: A device attached to the system is not functioning.\n      Is it an HID?\n"), myDev.m_dwError);
            break;
        case ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
            wprintf (_T("   CreateFile() failed. GetLastError() = %d\n      ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE: The handle is invalid.\n      CreateFile() failed?\n"), myDev.m_dwError);
            break;
        default:
            wprintf (_T("   CreateFile() failed. GetLastError() = %d\n"), myDev.m_dwError);
            break;
    }

    if (myDev.m_dwError == 0) {
        char   reqWeight[] = "W\r";
        char   resWeight[256] = {0};

        myDev.WriteStream (reqWeight, strlen (reqWeight));
        wprintf (_T("    Sent request now get response.\n"));
        Sleep (50);
        myDev.ReadStream (resWeight, 16);
        wprintf (_T("    Got response.\n"));
        if (resWeight[0] != '\n' || resWeight[9] != '\r') {
            wprintf (_T("    Unexpected format of response.\n"));
        }

        short sRet = UieScaleStatus (resWeight, myDev.m_dwBytesRead);

        resWeight[9] = 0;      // terminate the weight string so that we can write it out.
        wprintf (_T("   ScaleStatus = %d, Response from device - \"%S\"\n"), sRet, resWeight + 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Additional Information Developed**

Overview of INF Files from Microsoft MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-inf-files

[Stackoverflow Do I need to write my own host side USB driver for a CDC device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176939/do-i-need-to-write-my-own-host-side-usb-driver-for-a-cdc-device)

[Stackoverflow how to get vendor id and product id of a plugged usb device on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935184/how-to-get-vendor-id-and-product-id-of-a-plugged-usb-device-on-windows)

[Is it possible to “transplant” drivers between machines?](https://superuser.com/questions/617295/is-it-possible-to-transplant-drivers-between-machines) has a link to a document [Debugging USB Device Installation on Windows](http://www.asyndetic.com/2010/02/06/debugging-usb-device-installation-on-windows/) and this posting [Remove Windows Device Class in Registry](https://superuser.com/questions/985915/remove-windows-device-class-in-registry) has a bit more info.

[USB serial driver (Usbser.sys)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn707976(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft.

[USB device class drivers included in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538820(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: Your error checking is broken. You need to check function return values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what does checking function return values have to do with the questions that I am asking? I am running this in the Visual Studio debugger and checking quite a few things that I did not bother to mention. I also check the most necessary return value, the one from `CreateFile()` to determine if the open worked or not. This is a sample, learning application not production code.

Comment: For all we know, some of the functions are failing and your code cannot detect that. Omission of error checking is one of the major problems with code posted here in the winapi tag. It takes little effort to put in checking. You don't have to handle it properly. Just an assertion will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing with a modified USB Serial sample application indicates that when a USB device that creates a Virtual Serial Communications port is unplugged the Virtual Serial Port created is torn down and disappears from the port listing in Device Manager app of Control Panel.

When the device, a USB scale in this case, is plugged in and turned on the Virtual Serial Communications port reappears in Device Manager. However when the Virtual Serial Communications port is created, it is created with default serial port settings (baud rate, parity, etc.) and these may not be the same as for your actual device.

In summary it appears that the Virtual Serial Communications port settings apply regardless of whether the port is opened as a COM port or if the USB device path name is used with the `CreateFile()`.

I am still investigating the Virtual Serial Port not automatically being created when using POS Ready 7 and will update this answer once I know more. However preliminary comparison between Windows 7 and POS Ready 7 is showing that a file that specifies `usbser.sys`, mdmcpq.inf, that is on my Windows 7 PC is not on the POS Ready 7 terminal in the folder C:\Windows\inf.

See [The INF File](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/oney_wdm/ch12b.htm) for a write up on the .inf file structure and the various sections. It is a bit old however it seems to cover the basics in a readable manner.

I modified the function `CreateEndPoint()` in the question to the following along with a change to the class and the constructor to create a set of default communication port settings for my scale.

The class and the constructor now contain a set of defaults for the communication port settings (9600 baud, 7 data bits, one stop bit, even parity for the scale) and look like:

```
class UsbSerialDevice
{
public:
    UsbSerialDevice();
    UsbSerialDevice(DWORD BaudRate, BYTE ByteSize = 8, BYTE Parity = NOPARITY, BYTE StopBits = ONESTOPBIT);
    ~UsbSerialDevice();
    int CreateEndPoint (wchar_t *wszVendorId);
    int SetCommPortSettings (DWORD BaudRate, BYTE ByteSize = 8, BYTE Parity = NOPARITY, BYTE StopBits = ONESTOPBIT);
    int CloseEndPoint ();
    int ReadStream (void *bString, size_t nBytes);
    int WriteStream (void *bString, size_t nBytes);
    int UpdateSettingsProxy (void);

    DWORD   m_dwError;          // GetLastError() for last action
    DWORD   m_dwErrorWrite;     // GetLastError() for last write
    DWORD   m_dwErrorRead;      // GetLastError() for last read
    DWORD   m_dwErrorCommState;
    DWORD   m_dwErrorCommTimeouts;
    DWORD   m_dwBytesWritten;
    DWORD   m_dwBytesRead;

    COMMTIMEOUTS  m_timeOut;           // last result from GetCommTimeouts(), updated by UpdateSettingsProxy()
    COMSTAT       m_statOut;           // last result from ClearCommError()
    DCB           m_commSet;           // last result from GetCommState(), updated by UpdateSettingsProxy()

private:
    HANDLE        m_hFile;
    DWORD         m_dwStatError;
    DCB           m_commSetDefault;    // the defaults used as standard
    wchar_t       m_portName[24];      // contains portname if defined for device in form \\.\\COMnn
};

UsbSerialDevice::UsbSerialDevice() :
    m_dwError(0),
    m_dwErrorWrite(0),
    m_dwErrorRead(0),
    m_dwBytesWritten(0),
    m_dwBytesRead(0),
    m_hFile(NULL)
{
    // initialize our COM port settings and allow people to change with 
    memset (&m_commSetDefault, 0, sizeof(m_commSetDefault));
    m_commSetDefault.DCBlength = sizeof(m_commSetDefault);
    m_commSetDefault.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    m_commSetDefault.ByteSize = 7;
    m_commSetDefault.Parity = EVENPARITY;
    m_commSetDefault.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    m_commSet.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
    m_portName[0] = 0;
}
```

The function `CreateEndPoint()` is modified so that after doing the `CreateFile()` to open the USB device using the pathname of the USB Device, it will now also set the communication port parameters.

An additional experimental change to the method was to check if a communications port name was also created and if so to generate the proper COM port specification to be used with `CreateFile()`. I plan to split out the `CreateEndPoint()` method into two methods, one to do a look up of the USB device and a second to actually do the open as I continue my investigation.

The format for the COM port specifier for `CreateFile()` for COM ports greater than COM9 appear to need the `\\.\` as a prefix. See [HOWTO: Specify Serial Ports Larger than COM9](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/115831) from Microsoft Support.

The new version of `CreateEndPoint()` looks like:

```
int UsbSerialDevice::CreateEndPoint (wchar_t *wszVendorId)
{
    HDEVINFO    hDevInfo;


    m_dwError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;

    // We will try to get device information set for all USB devices that have a
    // device interface and are currently present on the system (plugged in).
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, NULL, 0, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD    dwMemberIdx;
        BOOL     bContinue = TRUE;
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA         DevIntfData;

        // Prepare to enumerate all device interfaces for the device information
        // set that we retrieved with SetupDiGetClassDevs(..)
        DevIntfData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
        dwMemberIdx = 0;

        // Next, we will keep calling this SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(..) until this
        // function causes GetLastError() to return  ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS. With each
        // call the dwMemberIdx value needs to be incremented to retrieve the next
        // device interface information.
        for (BOOL bContinue = TRUE; bContinue; ) {
            PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA  DevIntfDetailData;
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA    DevData;
            DWORD  dwSize;

            dwMemberIdx++;
            SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, dwMemberIdx, &DevIntfData);

            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) break;

            // As a last step we will need to get some more details for each
            // of device interface information we are able to retrieve. This
            // device interface detail gives us the information we need to identify
            // the device (VID/PID), and decide if it's useful to us. It will also
            // provide a DEVINFO_DATA structure which we can use to know the serial
            // port name for a virtual com port.

            DevData.cbSize = sizeof(DevData);

            // Get the required buffer size. Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail with
            // a NULL DevIntfDetailData pointer, a DevIntfDetailDataSize
            // of zero, and a valid RequiredSize variable. In response to such a call,
            // this function returns the required buffer size at dwSize.

            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &DevIntfData, NULL, 0, &dwSize, NULL);

            // Allocate memory for the DeviceInterfaceDetail struct. Don't forget to
            // deallocate it later!
            DevIntfDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize);
            DevIntfDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

            if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &DevIntfData, DevIntfDetailData, dwSize, &dwSize, &DevData))
            {
                // Finally we can start checking if we've found a useable device,
                // by inspecting the DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath variable.
                //
                // The DevicePath looks something like this for a Brecknell 67xx Series Serial Scale
                // \\?\usb#vid_1a86&pid_7523#6&28eaabda&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
                //
                // The VID for a particular vendor will be the same for a particular vendor's equipment.
                // The PID is variable for each device of the vendor.
                //
                // As you can see it contains the VID/PID for the device, so we can check
                // for the right VID/PID with string handling routines.

                // See https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/usb/usbview/vndrlist.h

                if (wcsstr (DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath, wszVendorId)) {
                    HKEY   hKey;

                    m_dwError = 0;
                    // To find out the serial port for our scale device,
                    // we'll need to check the registry:
                    hKey = SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(hDevInfo, &DevData, DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL, 0, DIREG_DEV, KEY_READ);

                    if (hKey != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                        DWORD    dwSize = 0, dwType = 0;
                        wchar_t  lpData[16] = {0};

                        dwType = REG_SZ;
                        dwSize = sizeof(lpData);
                        LONG queryStat = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, _T("PortName"), NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&lpData[0], &dwSize);
                        RegCloseKey(hKey);
                        if (queryStat == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                            wcscpy (m_portName, L"\\\\.\\");
                            wcsncat (m_portName, lpData, dwSize / sizeof(wchar_t));
                        }
                    } else {
                        m_dwError = GetLastError();
                    }

                    m_hFile = CreateFile (DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
                    if (m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                        m_dwError = GetLastError();
                    } else {
                        m_dwError = 0;
                        GetCommState (m_hFile, &m_commSet);
                        m_commSet = m_commSetDefault;
                        SetCommState (m_hFile, &m_commSet);
                        m_dwErrorCommState = GetLastError();
                        GetCommState (m_hFile, &m_commSet);

                        GetCommTimeouts (m_hFile, &m_timeOut);
                        m_timeOut.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
                        m_timeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
                        m_timeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 5000;
                        SetCommTimeouts (m_hFile, &m_timeOut);
                        GetCommTimeouts (m_hFile, &m_timeOut);
                        m_dwErrorCommTimeouts = GetLastError();
                    }
                    bContinue = FALSE;    // found the vendor so stop processing after freeing the heap.
                }
            }

            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, DevIntfDetailData);
        }

        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**POS Ready 7 Investigation**

Looking back on the Windows 7 PC which seems to work fine with the scale, we looked in the driver details for the Virtual Serial Communications port using Device Manager from the Control Panel. The driver details indicated that the driver being used was CH341S64.SYS provided by www.winchiphead.com and the Property "Inf name" has a value of `oem50.inf`. I found a forum post http://doityourselfchristmas.com/forums/showthread.php?14690-CH340-USB-RS232-Driver which provides a link to a driver download at http://www.winchiphead.com/download/CH341/CH341SER.ZIP however another version available from http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_ZIP.html may be more up to date.

Putting the downloaded zip file, CH341SER.ZIP from the later on to the POS Ready 7 terminal, I unzipped the contents and ran `SETUP.EXE` in the folder `CH341SER` (there were two folders in the zip file and the one called INSTALL seemed for device development) which displayed a dialog and allowed me to install the `CH341SER.INF`. Once the install completed, when I plugged in the USB scale, the device was recognized and a Virtual Serial Communications port was created and my test application worked.

I did find some documentation however it was all in Chinese. Google Translate provided a readable version of the USB device documentation. It looks like there is additional work to be done for device management when the scale may be unplugged/replugged while in use.

**One other strange thing** is that the scale is now using a different COM port name, COM5 rather than COM4. Looking in the Advanced Settings it appears that COM4 is "In Use" though not showing in the list of ports. Further experiments indicates that the COM port name used for the scale device depends on which of the two front panel USB ports are plugged into. I had originally plugged into the left one and today, plugged into the right USB port with the result of the Virtual Serial Communications port being created with a new COM port name.

However since we are using the USB path in the `CreateFile()`, no change was needed in the USB sample test application.

**Further testing with POS Ready 7 using three USB to Serial converter cables** showed that different vendor's cables had the same vendor id and product code in the USB path. The USB path also changed depending on which USB port a cable was plugged into. In some cases only the last digit in the path name differed. An interesting experiment would be if a USB hub is connected to a USB port and then USB connections are made to the hub what does the path name look like then?

Comment: when you plug some USB device, the PDO is created. windows ask it for device/hardware/compatible IDs and based on it try create FDO for it (first look in registry, if not found - in inf files). if FDO created (in current case by Virtual Serial Communications) - it attached to PDO. no different are you open file by PDO (`\\?\usb#vid_1a86&pid_7523*`) or FDO (`\\?\com*`) name - all request in all case will be send to the top of stack device - so for FDO. how i understand your problem when no FDO created in system, because no inf/sys files. and direct read request to PDO return `STATUS_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: so you need install driver for you device first

Comment: @RbMm thank you for your comment. I will need to lookup some of your acronyms as this is not an area I have sufficient technical knowledge to understand your comment. I am currently reading Microsoft Windows Internals to better understand the Windows architecture and specifically USB device driver stack. It is currently looking like I need an appropriate .inf file on the POS Ready 7 terminal. The file mdmcpq.inf is missing from the terminal's C:\Windows\inf folder. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn707976(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: you need read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540535(v=vs.85).aspx - USB bus driver create PDO for device - this is always on all system. then system try create FDO for device. and here you have problem - but it can be fixed by coping inf/cat/sys files (must be `usb\vid_1a86&pid_7523` in inf). about which name use to open device - no different. if device <B> attached to device <A> - yo can open by name <A> or <B> - but in both case all your request to device (including reading) will be send to <B> device, even if you open <A>

Comment: @RbMm I have found a detailed section on PnP Manager in Windows Internals Part 2, Sixth Edition (thanks to my O'Reilly Safari Books subscription) and now understand PDO and FDO driver layers architecture. How do I make a .inf file available to describe the mapping of a USB vendor id and product id to a particular driver such as usbser.sys? It appears there is an installation program. I saw unknown USB device in Device Manager when connecting scale USB. I think this is because mdmcpq.inf is missing from the terminal. How do I make it available?

Comment: you can copy inf+cat+sys files in some folder and call `UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(0, L"usb\\vid_1a86&pid_7523", ..)`
(this after your hardware already how minumum once plugged ) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553534(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: or use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544717(v=vs.85).aspx - `DiInstallDriver`

Answer (score 3):

The communication of the PC that runs windows (USB host) and the scale (USB device) obeys the USB protocol. If you install **libusb** for windows you can get similar informations as the PC gets from the USB device, when using `lsusb -v`. It is possible for a USB device to implement more than one USB class.

If the USB device creates a Virtual COM port it for sure implements the CDC ACM class (Communication Device Class Abstract Control Model) beside this it can also implement other USB classes like Mass Storage class,...

**Direct** communication with USB device depends also on what device classes it implements and its interfaces and endpoints. If the USB device implements a CDC ACM (Virtual COM) you use the specific RS-232 commands (i.e. https://www.commfront.com/pages/3-easy-steps-to-understand-and-control-your-rs232-devices or send a hexadecimal 'D' to a multimeter to receive the measured value) if it implements the Mass Storage class you normally use *bulk transfers*

To change the mode of the USB device you use *control transfers* (see USB in a nutshell)

In this link is how Win determines which driver to load after determining the USB class of the device https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj649944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

i do not know how Brecknell implemented the CDC ACM device class that is the Virtual COM however normally any Win version that supports USB should be able to load a driver for a CDC ACM device class (Virtual COM) so you are correct this seems to be **a problem of the .inf driver file** or the driver loading mechanism (maybe a problem of the Brecknell CDC ACM implementation but i do not think so)

Then, if Win loads a working driver the normal way is what you did: use `CreateFile()` with the COM that is assigned to the USB device.

*The strange thing is that if I then use the application which opens the Virtual Serial Communication port, COM4, that application works fine and the scale reports the weight of items.* <- this is not strange, strange is that some Win versions do not recognize a CDC USB device .
The standard driver for CDC devices seems to be `USBser.sys` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/dn707976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
If you search 'windows does not recognize CDC device' you get results

*If a USB device creates a Virtual Serial Communications port when it is plugged in then is it required to only use the Virtual Serial port by specifying the communications port, COM4 in my case, in the CreateFile() call?* Yes, if a USB device implements a virtual COM it is the easiest way to use this COM to communicate with this device

See also http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml USB in a nutshell

standard USB: device descriptor (class) -> interface -> (configuration) -> endpoint

Comment: Thank you for so much information. I will spend some time reading and reviewing it. I appreciate you going into so much detail and the links to additional information.

Comment: I am wondering if there is some kind of limitation with POS Ready 7 and driver installation which is not there for Windows 7. I did find a sample source code that iterates over the installed USB devices and determines the COM port for a particular USB device that has a Virtual Serial Communication port. That source worked fine and using the COM port with the `CreateFile()` to work with the Virtual Serial port including being able to open the port after unplugging and replugging the USB cable. This would be the best approach if we can get POS Ready 7 to do the install of the scale driver.

Comment: maybe see this https://cld.pt/dl/download/b4930527-31e7-41ae-a533-30545642170d/Almeno%20Rocha%20-%20Ficheiros%20de%20Trabalho/DRIVERS/SAM4S%20GIANT%20Tool%20V2.07/MANUALS/GIANT-Tool%20UserGuide%28Eng%29.pdf my internet is too slow i can not load this. else here is a pay solution http://www.thesycon.de/eng/usb_cdcacm.shtml however normally this should not be necessary. Contact microsoft for this ...

Comment: Thank you for the link to the pdf document. I have done testing with SAM4S and have a reseller using some of their equipment.This doc describes a setup utility for one of their receipt printers. It appears that it offers USB connectivity and depends on Virtual Serial Communication port to implement that much like my scale. Unfortunately there is no technical information about the driver setup. It appears they are also using a Virtual COM driver for LAN/WLAN and there is a printer driver that must be installed to support it. Actually that part of the doc is a bit confusing. lol

Comment: I am going to do further research into POS Ready 7. My impression is that each vendor offers a version of POS Ready 7 that is tailored to their equipment so there may be some additional software component available from the equipment vendor, NCR. You have been a big help and I appreciate your time. I will let you know how this turns out with a comment to your posting here.

Comment: I have a partial answer for the failure for my sample USB Serial Communication application to fail when the USB is unplugged and then replugged. I am still working on the POS Ready 7 question. However I suspect that there may be a Windows update settings which is the problem so that if POS Ready 7 does not recognize the device then it does not try to locate a USB driver. In many cases POS Ready 7 is used with updates turned off in order to prevent problem updates from causing terminal software to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two issues, and it's probably not viable for us to tell them apart.

I say this because you link `ReadFile` problems to the device name. However, `ReadFile` works on a **`HANDLE`**. The function which takes a name and converts it into a `HANDLE` is called `CreateFile`. That means `ReadFile` doesn't even *know* on what name it's operating.

This misunderstanding also explains a few other behaviors. For instance, when you unplug the device, the `HANDLE` becomes invalid, and it stays invalid. Replugging the device may restore the name, but not the `HANDLE`.

Comment: I understand how `CreateFile()` and `ReadFile()` work. The test procedure I use with the sample application is to put something on the scale, run the application and look at the console window output after it terminates. So the USB is not unplugged when the application is running. What you have provided is of no help whatsoever.