# C# - Get List of all USB Printers

Tags: c#, usb, printers

How can I get a list of all the connected USB printers using C#? I need to show in a Listbox the name of all USB printers.

Edit: System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters does not solve my problem, I need only USB printers, not installed printers.

Edit2: My real objective is get device instance ID from the printer name, which has been answered here: [Figuring which printer name corresponds to which device ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651949/figuring-which-printer-name-corresponds-to-which-device-id). So, I need printer name take from a list of USB printers to use GetUSBPath(string PrinterName).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the list of all printers in computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354435/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer)

Comment: try the `ManagementObjectSearcher`

Answer (score 1):

I used this code my old project i hope it helpfull for you =)

First you have to add this library: `using System.Drawing.Printing;`

```
foreach (string printers in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            comboBoxName.Items.Add(printers);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this give me: Microsoft XPS Document Writer (wrong), HP Deskjet 3630 series (OK - usb), HP Deskjet 1010 series (OK - usb), Fax (wrong). I need only USB printers.

Comment: You can remove thats on your control. That code will give you all printers. These are default :)