# FileStream.Dispose throws UnauthorizedAccessException how to handle disposing?

Tags: c#, usb

The `FileStream` is created from `SafeHandle` that points directly to `USB Printing Support` driver, so it is not a regular `FileStream`.

Now I am trying to fix a problem when a user unplugs and re-plugs the USB device. A new handle is created and the old one now points somewhere else. I need to reinitialize the connection, but before creating a new one my instinct is to Dispose the old resources

> Dispose everything that is disposable

Trying to dispose this `FileStream` I get `UnauthorizedAccessException` with regular message `Access to the path is denied`. Do I just wrap my Dispose calls in method Disconnect to `try/catch` and leave them undisposed as is? Maybe there is a better way for USB I/O than `FileStream`?

Here is some code:

```
public void Connect()
{
    Disconnect();
    _printerHandle = UsbPrinterResolver.OpenUSBPrinter(ConnectionString);
    _printerStream = new FileStream(_printerHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
}
protected void Disconnect()
{
    _printerStream?.Dispose(); // only works when the usb connection is working and valid
    _printerHandle?.Dispose();
    _printerStream = null;
    _printerHandle = null;
}
```

The `UsbPrinterResolver` is actually the one from question [Figuring which printer name corresponds to which device ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651949/figuring-which-printer-name-corresponds-to-which-device-id/10728780#10728780) I just modified the `//FIXME` part. But the resolved handles seemed to work great.

Comment: Where is `UsbPrinterResolver` is it from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10728780/14868997

Comment: yes that is the one, I have fixed that `//FIXME` part though. Besides this Dispose problem it works great. I should actually link that question.

Comment: Maybe edit that answer with the new `FIXME` bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileStream` internally flushes the stream before disposing.

So you just need to catch the exception on the outside of whatever is disposing this object.

As far as disposing the handle: it will be closed regardless, you don't need to dispose that because the stream "owns" the handle. See [the source code here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,8270a043211dafd8). So you don't need to keep it around.

```cs
public void Connect()
{
    Disconnect();
    var printerHandle = UsbPrinterResolver.OpenUSBPrinter(ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        _printerStream = new FileStream(_printerHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    }
    catch
    {
        printerHandle.Dispose();  // need to dispose the handle if FileStream ctor fails
        throw;
    }
}

protected void Disconnect()
{
    _printerStream?.Dispose();
    _printerStream = null;
}
```

Comment: But if the flush happens before any resource release and it throws, woudn’t that leave everything undisposed?

Comment: No look at the source code it's disposing the handle in a `finally`

Comment: You are right! I didin’t take note of that, thank you.