# Print image to Zebra printer from file

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have a dedicated text file "**MyImages.txt**" containing images that I want to be printed on my label. All images are loaded into printer memory using the command `~DG`, for example:

```
~DGLOGO1.GRF,01536,008,[image]
```

When I am trying to print this image from the same text file "**MyImages.txt**" everything works fine:

```
^FX---MyImages.txt---^FS
^FT736,1152^XGLOGO2.GRF,1,1^FS
```

However, when I am using a different file, let's call it "**MyNewLabel.txt**", and call the same command

```
^FX---MyNewLabel.txt---^FS
^FT736,1152^XGLOGO2.GRF,1,1^FS
```

... then the label is not printed. I would like to understand why this is not working. I have loaded the image into the memory upfront sending "MyImages.txt" to the printer, then I send "MyNewLabel.txt" to the printer - so imo the printer should recall the image from its memory...

Comment: Go to your printer's web address and see what files it has stored on the drive. If the printer is too simple to have a web address, print the configuration label with the list of the stored files.

Comment: @GSerg Unfortunately access to the printer web address is blocked by the customer's security policy. Is there any other way?

Comment: Print the configuration label with the list of the stored files? Request the configuration label with `^HW`?

Comment: I am trying to print the label as follows but no label is printed:

^XA
^HWR:*.*
^XZ

Comment: `^HW` does not print a label. It returns the information on the same connection. You need to [read the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659778/11683).

Comment: Finally I got access to the web service and investigated the issue. In fact the image has been stored on the volatile drive R: and in between the printer has been switched off and on and so the graphics got lost. I downloaded the graphics again to the non-volatile memory E: . Now everything works as expected. Thanks!